# Como puedo obtener la fecha de hoy desde un string y no el valor completo de este?

Tags: c#, webservice, string, datetime

Tengo una aplication la cual necesito exportar varios valores. En uno de ellos tengo un string que me devuelve una fecha con hora incluida "2/8/2017 10:26:35 AM".

Lo que necesito es extraer esta string pero solamente validando el dia en que se ejecuta el codigo.

Ejemplo:

Si el string tiene "2/8/2017 10:26:35 AM" necesito el valor de "2/8/2017".

He tratado de usar Contains(DateTime.Today) pero no me resulta.

Como puedo lograr esto?

Saludos

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿la fecha de tu `string` está en formato `MM/dd/YYYY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tienes un string así:

```
string fecha_de_prueba = "2/8/2017 10:26:35 AM";
```

De la cual solo deseas obtener el día, mes y año, puedes optar por:

Separar el valor del string `fecha_de_prueba` de la siguiente manera:

```
string fecha_de_prueba = "2/8/2017 10:26:35 AM";
string fecha_ddmmyyyy = fecha_de_prueba.Split(' ')[0];
// Resultado: 2/8/2017
```

O, simplificado:

```
string fecha_de_prueba = "2/8/2017 10:26:35 AM";
fecha_de_prueba = fecha_de_prueba.Split(' ')[0];
// Resultado: 2/8/2017
```

---

Para comparar las fechas, puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
DateTime fecha_actual = DateTime.Today;
// Valor: 08/02/2016 00:00:00

string fecha_de_prueba = "2/8/2017 10:26:35 AM";
DateTime fecha_a_comparar = DateTime.Parse(fecha_de_prueba.Split(' ')[0]);
// Valor: 02/08/2017 00:00:00

// Aquí validas que los días de ambas fechas sean las mismas
// (tal como indicas en tu pregunta).
if (fecha_actual.Day == fecha_a_comparar.Day) {
   // TODO: Ejecutar tu código.
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta. Me parece bien pero el programa se va a ejecutar diariamente, por lo cual necesito la fecha del dia que se va a ejecutar y hacer un match si esa fecha corresponde al dia que se ejecuta o no.

Comment: @Aarancibia he actualizado mi respuesta. Si deseas comparar que ambas fechas sean iguales _(es decir, en mi ejemplo: `fecha_actual` y `fecha_actual`)_ puedes usar: `if (fecha_actual.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == fecha_a_comparar.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))`.

Comment: Excelente! muchas gracias me resulto como yo esperaba!.

Answer (score 0):

Si sabes que luego de la fecha siempre viene un espacio en blanco, entonces puedes usar:

```
string source = "2/8/2017 10:26:35 AM";
var result = source.Split(new Char[] {' '}, 2).First();
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta. Me parece bien pero el programa se va a ejecutar diariamente, por lo cual necesito la fecha del dia que se va a ejecutar y hacer un match si esa fecha corresponde al dia que se ejecuta o no.

Answer (score 0):

Trata de la siguiente manera

```
`string fecha_de_prueba = "2/8/2017 10:26:35 AM";
 string pattern = "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
 DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
        fecha_de_prueba, 
        pattern, 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 string newstrDate = date.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

Tambien hay un TryParseExact que valida antes en caso que la fecha pueda no tener el formato

Answer (score 0):

Solo por ampliar las respuestas, en mi opinión cuando se trabaja con fechas siempre es mejor utilizar el tipo dedicado a ello,o sea `DateTime`.

En este caso, lo que yo haría sería comparar la propiedad `Date` de `DateTime`, lo que resultaría en algo así:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("9/2/2017 10:26:35 AM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
if (DateTime.Now.Date==dt1.Date)
{

}
```